# How does the simple coding interpretation exactly work?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, regression-coefficients

I don't understand how **simple coding** works in the text below (original content [here](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/)).

Once we fit the regression model: ***Why*** would the coefficient that we fit to **race.f1** help us compare Levels **1** and **2**?

[image]

For example, if we get the results below from such a model. **Why** is it that I can interpret that the difference in the response variable between Level 1 and 2 is `11.5417 - 1.7417` ?

[image]

Comment: Look at the coefficients you get when you subtract the column `race.f2 (1 vs.3)` from the column `race.f1 (1 vs 2)` and compare them to the coefficients in your contrast $0\times(51.6784) + 1\times (11.5417) + (-1)\times (1.7417) + 0\times(7.5968)$.

Comment: Thanks @whuber That makes intuitive sense, but how does one reach that result using algebra of expectations? I.e. why is it that the difference in coefficients for these variables, with this particular coding, results in $E[Y_{f1}-Y_{f2}]$ (i.e. $E[Y|race=f1]$ - $E[Y|race=f2]$) ?

Comment: It is a direct consequence of the linearity of expectations.

Comment: Thanks @whuber I see that know. Now, how about the argument that the intercept is the **grand mean** in simple coding? I am assuming that it also comes from algebra of expectations somehow, but I fail to see why that is exactly the case.